# Trying to combine two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine two dataframes. This is my code:

```
x = df.loc[df['continent'] == 'South America']
y = df.loc[df['continent'] == 'North America']
Americas  =x + y
Americas
```

When this prints, it just gives back NaN values

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By combining, if you meant appending; then try this... means daya y below data x;

```
Americas = pd.concat([x,y])
```

Comment: Worth to mention he can also do a more smart conditioning:
`df.loc[(df['continent'] == 'South America') | (df['continent'] == 'North America')]`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting `NaN` values is that you're making a binary add `+` (which is equivalent to [**`pandas.DataFrame.add`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html)) between two dataframes that have not the same indexes. Try to add `.reset_index()` to both `x` and `y` and you'll see a different behaviour.

To achieve what you're looking for, you can use [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) instead :

```
Americas = pd.concat([x,y], ignore_index=True))
```

Or simply [**`pandas.Series.isin`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) if there is no need to the intermediates dataframes :

```
Americas = df.loc[df['continent'].isin(['South America', 'North America'])]
```